# How to set (or clear) default card description in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

When I create a new card in any of my boards, the card has unsaved edits already posted into the description of the card.  This description is from a card I created, once upon a time, but it now gets added by default to every card I create.

This seems an awful lot like a bug, but I suppose it might be a feature.

Here is an example:

[image: Sample Illustrating the Bug]

My questions are:

1. Does anybody else see this behavior?
2. If this is a feature and not a bug, how do you turn it off (or clear out the default description)?

I've looked around at as many of the board settings as I can find and I've Googled around for any insights into this, but all to no avail so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a bug.

Try clearing your localStorage.  You can do this by going to trello.com and running `javascript:localStorage.clear()` from the address bar.